# I am logged in, but where is the logout link?

Tags: support, logout

I just spent twenty minutes looking through questions.

Where is the link to log out from Stack Exchange? I would prefer logging out from all sites, but just Stack Overflow would be nice.

I log in using email/password, I guess.

Comment: What are you browsing with? Are you on Desktop version, mobile version or app?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a desktop browser, there is a "log out" option next to the current site's name in the top-right menu:

[image]

This will log you out from all the network sites.

Comment: This question has been answered already. Please avoid answering duplicate questions. Instead vote to close or flag the question for closure. Answers to duplicate questions are not really helpful to future users. If you think that there is something the original question does not cover, edit or add an answer to that question.

Comment: @MEE I realised later that this was a duplicate. I had actually found the other one while researching, followed the *other question's dupe*, and noticed it was about a different situation. So the incorrect dupe on the other question was what confused me :)

Comment: yes, that is confusing, but still the other post is answered correctly and therefore it can be marked as a dupe for this. Also on meta sometimes strongly related posts are marked as dupes.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "communities" icon. On the left of where it says "Meta Stack Exchange", there's a "log out" link. Click on it and it will take you to a logout page.

[image]

Comment: This question has been answered already. Please avoid answering duplicate questions. Instead vote to close or flag the question for closure. Answers to duplicate questions are not really helpful to future users. If you think that there is something the original question does not cover, edit or add an answer to that question.

Comment: @MEE I was not aware this was a dup.

Comment: I am not directly saying that you have bad intentions. I am just saying that this is discouraged for several reasons. The canonical duplicate can be found by entering "log out" and then choosing the second post (and eventually following the dupe chain). (Note: this is not supposed to mean the OP didn't search correctly)